# Problem with evaluating XPath while using Apache Synapse

Tags: xpath, ubuntu, apache-synapse

I'm trying to run Apache Synapse samples on ubuntu 11.04 64-bit and I have found problem with evaluating XPath expression in sample nr 2.

My XPath expression:

```
$ <definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse http://synapse.apache.org/ns/2010/04/configuration/synapse_config.xsd">

<sequence name="main">
    <switch source="//m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
        <case regex="IBM">
            <!-- the property mediator sets a local property on the *current* message -->
            <property name="symbol" value="Great stock - IBM"/>
        </case>
        <case regex="MSFT">
            <property name="symbol" value="Are you sure? - MSFT"/>
        </case>
        <default>
            <!-- it is possible to assign the result of an XPath expression as well -->
            <property name="symbol" expression="fn:concat('Normal Stock - ', //m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol)"/>
        </default>
    </switch>
    <log level="custom">
        <!-- the get-property() XPath extension function allows the lookup of local message properties
                    as well as properties from the Axis2 or Transport contexts (i.e. transport headers) -->
        <property name="symbol" expression="get-property('symbol')"/>
        <!-- the get-property() function supports the implicit message headers To/From/Action/FaultTo/ReplyTo -->
        <property name="epr" expression="get-property('To')"/>
    </log>
    <!-- Send the messages where they are destined to (i.e. the 'To' EPR of the message) -->
    <send/>
</sequence>
```

It is run on following data:

```
$ <soapenv:Body><m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"><m0:request><m0:symbol>IBM</m0:symbol></m0:request></m0:getQuote></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

And result is:

2011-08-08 15:37:04,227 [-] [HttpClientWorker-1] DEBUG SwitchMediator XPath : //m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol evaluates to :

2011-08-08 15:37:04,227 [-] [HttpClientWorker-1] DEBUG SwitchMediator None of the switch cases matched - executing default

while it should go to:

```
$<case regex="IBM">
        <!-- the property mediator sets a local property on the *current* message -->
        <property name="symbol" value="Great stock - IBM"/>
    </case>
```

Does anyone knows what can be the problem? I have installed that ubuntu few days ago, so there is possibility, that there is something missing on that system.

Answer (score 0):

Try with full xpath..

```
 <switch xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" source="//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol">
```